Appwrite failing when setting up Google OAuth2 : Error 400 Invalid `success` param: URL host must be one of: localhost, cloud.appwrite.io, appwrite.io
Error 400
Invalid success param: URL host must be one of: localhost, cloud.appwrite.io, appwrite.io
Type
general_argument_invalid

I am building an ai chatbot that is hosted on my own website mywebsite.com under a subdomain of mybot.mywebsite.com with webpages

"mybot.mywebsite.com/login.html" for the authentication page using OAuth2.0 with providers like Google
"mybot.mywebsite.com/callback.html" for callback page to return from authetication page so that I can save the user info
"mybot.mywebsite.com/chatbot.html" for the UX of chatbot, which calls appwrite function to get ai's response

To power my website, I have set up appwrite backend-as-a-service for oauth2.0 and I have written a few appwrite functions using python runtime

chatbot function that takes a question and some additional context and responds with a line of text
save-user-info function to save the user's information after successful authentication

The problem I am running into is that, when I call sdk.account.createOAuth2Session with "https://mybot.mywebsite.com/callback.html" as successful URL and "https://mybot.mywebsite.com/login.html for failure url, I am getting an error saying that the success URL needs to be a website using cloud.appwrite.io or appwrite.io
I saw a support entry asking to add my web page hostiong site to my appwrite project's "custom domains". I tried doing it and the website is getting (see attached)

and the error of
Error 400 Invalid success param: URL host must be one of: localhost, cloud.appwrite.io, appwrite.io
Type : general_argument_invalid
is persisting

The domain of your web app is supposed to be added as a platform to your project on the Overview page. This is done to ensure only verified client apps can access your Appwrite project (thus, preventing CORS errors).

If you have added an API key or any other platform already, this may be visible as shown below:

Adding the web app URL here should resolve the error. If it persists, you can also join the Appwrite Discord server and share it in our support channel to communicate directly with the team.
